# Unable to download/ install font apk

Tags: apk, fonts

I made a font, but I didn't build it, instead I used [this website](http://convertfonts.com/ttf-to-apk.php) to do it. The apk install seemed fine. I wanted to try it out on SG2, so I sent it to my Gmail account in an email, I tried to download it and the file install couldn't go through because of the parse error pop up. If its an apk file, why isn't this working? Is there something wrong with the font? (Lookout scanned and said it was a safe apk).

I even put it on my 4shared account and tried to download it that way, still get parse error. Did Gmail corrupt it perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The web app hasn't built a correct APK.

To install a font, you don't need font-to-apk converters. Just put ttf file on sdcard and use a Font Installer from Play Store. For this, rooted device is required. If you aren't rooted, font-to-apk converters are useless.

Comment: I don't know how to even begin to root my device. But thank you so much anyways.